# How to print only rows that have a value in the 4th column?

Tags: python, unix

I apologize if this has been asked/answered; I couldn't find an answer by searching.

I have a very long text file, and only a tiny fraction of the rows have a value in the 4th column, which is what I care about. How can I print only those lines?

Here is my data:

```
gi|254160123|ref|NC_012967.1|   585236  C       
gi|254160123|ref|NC_012967.1|   585237  C       
gi|254160123|ref|NC_012967.1|   585238  A       
gi|254160123|ref|NC_012967.1|   585239  C   4   
gi|254160123|ref|NC_012967.1|   585240  A       
gi|254160123|ref|NC_012967.1|   585241  A       
gi|254160123|ref|NC_012967.1|   585242  C       
gi|254160123|ref|NC_012967.1|   585243  T   16  
gi|254160123|ref|NC_012967.1|   585244  G   6   
gi|254160123|ref|NC_012967.1|   585245  C   2   
gi|254160123|ref|NC_012967.1|   585246  G   3   
gi|254160123|ref|NC_012967.1|   585247  C   9
```

I want to print only lines with a value in the fourth column (rows 4,8,9,10,11,12 in this example).

Comment: Provide small sample of your input file.

Comment: for this problem, you could have got better help at unix stack exchange, but you can use **awk** or **gawk** to achieve your target.

If you are unaware, AWK is an interpreted programming language designed for text processing and typically used as a data extraction and reporting tool. Its GNU cousin is GAWK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for a solution in Python, here's one. It reads each line of the file, then splits it into columns on the whitespace; if the columns after the fourth (index 3) are empty, it doesn't print.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.split()[3:]:
            print line
```

You might find the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to be more robust when working with columnar files, but it's a bit overkill for the stated problem and doesn't preserve the format of the input.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not posted sample of your data file, I will give you a generic example on how to achieve extraction of specific columns using awk... You can use gawk(gnu-awk) as

well, the concept is similar,suppose you have a file (BBS-list),

```
alpo-net     555-3412     2400/1200/300     A
bites        555-1675     2400/1200/300     A
fooey        555-1234     2400/1200/300     B
foot         555-6699     1200/300          B
macfoo       555-6480     1200/300          A
sdace        555-3430     2400/1200/300     A
sabafoo      555-2127     1200/300          C
```

if you want to print second columns with first column records 'EXACT' match to 'foo'

you can use--

```
$ awk '$1 == "foo" { print $2 }' BBS-list
```

but since they are fooey, macfoo, sabafoo etc etc you will not get any output.

Here comes pattern matching, instead of "foo" you can use, pattern matching /foo/

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /foo/ { print $2 }' BBS-list
```

the result will be that of fooey, foot, macfoo and sabafoo,

```
555-1234
555-6699
555-6480
555-2127
```

example courtesy (univ. of Utah)

Hence for isolating the NULL you can use,

```
awk '$2==""' myfile.txt    //$2 means third column (as you asked)
```

But after researching and testing on my system I was baffled that I cant isolate null values using **awk**. It cant differentiate between NULL and Space.The problem is you have to specifically mention the delimiter. The best way to do is use **tab** as field separator. Hence you can use,

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"} $2=="" {print}' myfile.txt
```

I think this should solve your dilemma.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I don't think I stated my problem clearly enough. Sample data will help, as you suggested. I edited my question to include data. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use *awk* to print only those lines with four fields:

```
awk 'NF==4' /path/to/input   # Num Fields == 4
```

By default *awk* ignores leading and trailing blanks (which, in common locales, means "spaces and tabs").  Thus, your desired records will be seen as having four fields (`1st`*<tab>*`2nd`*<tab>*`3rd`*<tab>*`4th`*<tab>*), whereas the others will have three (`1st`*<tab>*`2nd`*<tab>*`3rd`*<tab><tab>*).  If no *awk* "action" is specified, the default action is to print the current line.